# Android Studio: Module won't show up in "Edit Configuration"

Tags: android-studio, module

I've imported a project to Android Studio with several subprojects.

I want to run a subproject.

I successfully made this subproject's build.gradle as a module.

In order to run it, I went to Run > edit configurations > + > Android Application.

**Problem: When I try to select a module, none show up in the drop down list.**

Why is this?

EDIT: it shows up as a module under Groovy but not showing under Android Application. How do I get it to show up under Android Application?

Comment: Hi Did you ever solve this issue i'm getting exactly the same issue.

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27501885/2835520) help, solved my problem like yours

Answer (score 166):

Make sure your **build.gradle** is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

not

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

After you have changed, please sync your gradle again.

[image]

Comment: That fixed my issue! Only synced with gradle again and AS recognized it.

Comment: I'm looking for this answer since 1h

Comment: For me just clicking the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" fixed it. I was really worried I had busted things beyond repair.

Comment: Before doing any changes to your gradle file, just close the project *file-->close* and then re-open the project. It may be Android Studio caching problem.

Comment: It is neither first nor second for me. I have only "// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules." in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 95):

I had similar issue when I selected parent directory of my project, I resolved by **Close Project -> Delete Project from Android Studio -> Import Project** by selecting right **build.gradle** file.

Make sure you select right build.gradle file while import.

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thanks!
Just had to close the project and import the gradle file again.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Android Studio is as annoying as ever.

Comment: closing and importing worked for me also. But not sure what is the root cause, at the first place

Comment: closing project and then just restarting android studio did work for me.
thank you guys.

Comment: I can't believe this is how a very big problem solved!

Comment: i cant seem to find "Delete Projecdt from Android Studio" option on the newest version of AS

Comment: @thagr You can try closing the project, then deleting/renaming the ".idea" folder (in the same folder as the build.gradle file).

Comment: This worked for me up until the part about selecting the build.gradle file. All I had to select was the root project folder, and it worked!

Comment: You can "Delete Project from Android Studio" by simply clicking the "X" next to the project name in the startup window

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem for Android 4.1.1

Answer (score 77):

In Android Studio 3.1.2 I have faced the same issue. I resolved this issue by click on "File->Sync Project with Gradle Files".This works for me. :)

Comment: Works also on 3.3.1

Comment: @aldok, not, it is not an accepted answer. It is a rare situation, when everything worked, but stopped. In many cases it won't work.

Comment: should be the ACCEPTED answer. +1

Comment: In some cases, this would've run on launching a new project in Android Studio, but it ran into a Gradle error which stopped it from completing - hence the lack of a configuration. Android Studio should have the Gradle error shown in the log output panel in that case.

Answer (score 74):

I fixed this by adding facets in **Module settings**. They were missing.
**right click on project** > **open Module settings** > **Facets** > **Add facets** ( "+" sign at the top ) > **Android**.
After adding facets you will have modules.
**UPDATE:**
For latest version of gradle, **Facets have been removed**, you can directly add modules now.
**right click on project** > **open Module settings** > **Add module** ( "+" sign at the top ) > **Phone and Tablet Application** (Now you can create a new module and configure it).

Comment: I have no clue what a facet is in this context (old name for module?) but the options seem to be missing in AS 1.0

Comment: @G_V the option 'Facets' exists under 'Project Settings' if you follow the menu described by sahil. I'm on AS 1.0 too and can see it

Comment: @kip2 It just shows me the project structure, nothing about facets. The + icon adds a new module, not a Facet. All my dependencies are in defined in Gradle build files per module. Maybe it only shows for projects using old versions of Gradle.

Comment: There should be a facets tab when you go to File > Project Structure

Comment: Also can't find Facets in Android 1.1.0

Comment: Let me edit this answer and provide you with some screenshots. It must be there, most of us are using Android Studio 1.1.0

Comment: @lka I have updated the answer, can you try and let me know if this works for you?

Comment: What if the module is already in the project but it's just not being recognized?

Comment: This answer is no longer correct for the newest version of Android Studios. Can someone give us the correct path to *open Module settings*?

Comment: @IanS, strange, but after I made these steps in AS 3.3, I got an empty project. But `Open Module settings` is in place, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIPBl.png.

Answer (score 51):

resolved this issue by clicking on "File->Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Comment: I wish I could upvote everytime I come here, thanks so much

Answer (score 26):

New project. Fixed this issue by clicking on "File->Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Comment: There's no such option when I click file

Answer (score 20):

I have tried all the options with no luck. So I have ended up with my working solution. Just make following steps:

1. Close android studio if open.
2. Copy module(project) in your current workspace.
3. Start android studio.
4. You will see added module in project structure.
5. Open `settings.gradle` of your project and `include ':YOUR_MODULE_NAME'`.
6. Sync gradle and you can see module is successfully added to your project.

Comment: `Open settings.gradle of your project and include ':YOUR_MODULE_NAME'` Worked for me THx.

Answer (score 16):

Try,

Files > Sync Project with Gradle Files
or
Files > Sync with File System
Should do the trick.

Comment: Have you read the previous comments? Is there any sense to duplicate the right answer?

Answer (score 15):

goto Android >> Gradle Scripts>>Build Gradle(Module :app)

make sure the first line of this file is like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

not like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Answer (score 13):

The following worked for me:

- edit the overall project's 'settings.gradle' file and add a line at the bottom to include your new module (include ':myNewModule') - e.g:

```js
include ':myNewModule'
```

- Synch gradle.
- Add a build.gradle file into your new module directory. You need to make sure the first line says 'apply plugin: 'com.android.application'. Simply copying a build.gradle from another module in your project, if you have one, seems to work.
- Synch Gradle
- Your module should now show up in 'Edit Configurations'

Comment: module (include*,* ':myNewModule') Missing a comma

Comment: I don't think a comma is needed there in cradle settings - I've added in a specific example.

Answer (score 10):

This mainly happens when you copy a library project and try to build it. The solution would be to add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

in the build.gradle file, instead of

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Then do a gradle sync

Comment: Several people have already added this solution to this question.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me: **File > Project Structure... > Modules > Green Plus Symbol > Import > Then Select The Project**

Comment: 6 short years later, it was File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> pick a module -> Build Tools Version -> latest version. Now I may have runnable configurations

Answer (score 6):

Android Studio 4+

1-  File -> Close project

2-  Delete .idea folder

3-  Open project again

Answer (score 5):

In your module build.gradle file make sure you have the correct plugin set.  it should be

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

Answer (score 5):

No configuration was deteched because IDE was unable to detech modules (`<no module>`).My **compileSdkVersion** and **buildToolsVersion** was **28** in **build.gradle** (*app module*)

```
  android {
        .
        .
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion 28
        .
        .
  }
```

But SDK was not installed. So then I installed it first and it worked for me !!!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It appears different solutions work for difference people, for me just closing the project and importing it again resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figure out why the module is not showed up when I add configuration for AndroidTests for a `com.android.library` module.

If you include your library module in your application's `build.gradle` like this:

```
compile project(':yourlibrary')
```

Since for library module it is compiled with `release` mode by default, you can't run `Android Tests` for it, that's why it won't show up in the module list.
I fixed it with following modification:

Add following configuration to the `build.gradle` of your library module:

```
     publishNonDefault true
```

By make following changes, you can `debug` compile your library by editing the `build.gradle` of your application module like following:

```
-    compile project(':yourlibrary')
+    debugCompile project(path: ':yourlibrary', configuration: 'debug')
+    releaseCompile project(path: ':yourlibrary', configuration: 'release')
```

Then sync it and you'll find it shows in the list.

Comment: please explain what is "yourlibrary"?

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman `yourlibrary` is the module name of your library module

Answer (score 3):

It was fixed for me after removing and re-adding the Android and Android-Gradle Facets in the Module Settings dialog.

Comment: Similar for me.  Removed and re-added the module themselves. Then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix it in Android Studio 1.3.1 by doing the following:

1. Make a new module from `File -> New -> New Module`
2. Name it something different, e.g. 'My Libary'
3. Copy an `.iml` file from an existing library module and change the name of the file and rename references in the `.iml` file
4. Add the module name to settings.gradle
5. Add the module dependency in your app's build.gradle file 'compile project(':mylibrary')'
6. Close and reopen Android Studio
7. Verify that Android Studio recognises the module as a library (should be bold)
8. Rename module's directory and module name by right clicking on the newly created module.
9. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

The following are methods to help you:

1. Close and Open Project again
2. Close and Open Android Studio
3. Clean Project
4. Rebuild Project
5. Instantiate and Restart
6. Make sure you have included `:app`
7. Import the Project

Answer (score 2):

I added this line to my app.iml file and it works

orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="appcompat-v7-19.1.0" level="project" />

Answer (score 2):

For me it was fixed by simply restarting Android Studio.. Like the good old days of Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

1. Close all Android Studio projects
2. Remove the project from the recent projects in Android Studio wizard
3. Restart Android Studio
4. Use import option (Import project- Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.) instead of open an existing
5. Project AS project
6. File -> Sync project with gradle files

Answer (score 2):

In my case problem was from a higher (or not downloaded) compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in build.gradle(app).
This was happened because of cloning project in another pc that not downloaded that sdk image.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes the errors exists in Android-manifest because of that there
>   is cross like image over run/debug configuration hence try to look
>   over if Android-manifest has any errors in just case.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, a newbie I boogered up my project, not sure how but it would not  longer run and complained about the manifest, the R, everything. I realized that some how in my settings.gradle did not have `include ':app'` once I added this, I was back on my way.

Answer (score 0):

Add your module in your applications .iml file like:

```
orderEntry type="module" module-name="yourmoudlename" exported=""
```

It works for me.

Comment: Can you format your answer? [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, nothing worked for me from all the answers. Finally, I clicked **Run > Edit Configuration**. On the left, u can choose a new main module and remove to deleted ones.

Answer (score 0):

If all the above doesn't work. Try to update your Android studio version.
Steps:
1. In Android Studio, select File > Settings (or Android Studio > Preference on Mac).
2. In the left pane, select Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates.
3. Be sure that Automatically check for updates is checked, and then select a channel from the drop-down list.
4. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was:

1. Right click on `app` project folder & select `Load/Unload Modules...`
2. Select `app` module, click `Unload >`, & click `OK`
3. Right click on `app` again & select `Load/Unload Modules...`
4. Select `app` module, click `< Load`, & click `OK`

`app` then appeared for me in the configurations list again.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers worked for me, so I deleted and reinstalled Android Studio. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with SDK license acceptance.
The problem was solved by downloading proper SDK version and license acceptance via SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

I just upgraded the version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0` in build.gradles to the latest version (currently 7.0.2) and it worked!

[image: upgrading gradle dependency]

Answer (score 0):

Before you import, make sure the project is error-free. In my case, I have to clean and rebuild the project before import.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try this that worked for me:

- Close all projects.
- From the wizard click on Plugins
- Look for Gradle and click on "Enable all"
- Go back to the Projects tab and click on your project

Answer (score -2):

These types of problems are related to AndroidManifest.xml,
so check the bugs thats are in AndroidManifest file.