# AndroidStudio newbie: when running, how to set a module

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run the application I get a message that I should choose the configuration.

When I do, I try to go with AndroidApplication, and then I get this message with an error saying module not specified. But when I try to choose a module from the dropdown, I get no options.

How can I fix this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: please follow the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368748/android-studio-module-wont-show-up-in-edit-configuration

Comment: I think u r not using a android studio project

Comment: @Sharath what do you mean? How should I do it?

Comment: @VishalRaj thank you - just followed that link and it said to choose the BuildGradle. The option in my setup is disabled. Would you know how to enable it?

Comment: you are trying to run eclipse project in android studio.

Comment: just check you manifest file and what is the default activity there. it should be MainActivity.

Comment: @HammadMukhtar yes I imported stuff from Eclipse. But now stuck in configurations. :(

Comment: @Tara I have my default activity named something else. Does it make a diffrence?

Comment: NO it does not make any difference.

Comment: if you are importing your file from eclipse to studio, it will ignore some files and it automatically create appropriate files. so thats not an issue. if you got some error while importing thats a problm

Comment: You must have made some mistake importing the project.

Comment: just go the project Windw and there you will find "File" tab. in file tab you will find "Project Structure" . in this you will find "Module" at left side and in that you will find "app". If you are on particular window it will select automatically app name. then you can run it.

Comment: Other wise in your window which you got " just write the name of the application in place of Unnamed" then it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible issues:

1) I don't see that you are using gradle(no gradle files shown in your 'project view', and I don't see the 'Gradle Scripts' drop down in the 'project view'.

This is an issue because it looks like this project is from Eclipse, not Android Studio. The inclusion of 'project.properties' hints at this too. Android Studio doesn't include the ant-based build system that can build a project from the Eclipse build system.

If this is the problem then close the project, and use the 'Import Project' wizard from the "Welcome to Android Studio" start window and re-import your proeject. This wizard will import the project for you and convert it to use the gradle build system.

2) If you ARE using gradle (and it just looks like you aren't)... Then this might be your problem...

In your 'settings.gradle' file (topmost level of your project...)

You should have something like

```
include ':<library-etc(obviously just placeholder)....>'
include ':app'
```

":app" here refers to the folder where your project lives. If it isn't in your 'settings.gradle' file then it won't be listed as a 'module' you can configure.

Comment: yes I am new to Gradle and I have not set it up correctly yet :(

Comment: I just tried to import project and it said it can't find Gradle home - what's the best way to set that up?

Comment: I installed gradle and did the right import and it worked. Now I have an error about manifest files, but at least it is something different :)

Comment: @Sharath The error is AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag