# Android studio project structure doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-studio

The  problem in android studio
after adding signing  or depedancy from  project structure and choose ok 
noting happen  nothing added to build.gradle  file

[image]

also i tried to use different android studio version  i was using version 1.5.1 
  and i tried android studio version 2.0 RC1 but the problem is still happening

i cannot add signing to my app module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Module won't show up in "Edit Configuration"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368748/android-studio-module-wont-show-up-in-edit-configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in sdk path the folder that contains sdk has some extra spaces