# Can't select my app in Edit Configurations

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the same problem as described in [Android Studio: Module won't show up in "Edit Configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368748/android-studio-module-wont-show-up-in-edit-configuration) but none of the solutions works for my Android Studio 3.2

I have inported a project, (probably) successfully compiled it and now wanted to run it - but the dialogue behind "Edit Configurations" does not give me the possibility to select and use my application.

From the other thread: I do not have a file where I could change

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Changing somethin in "Facets" is not possible, the options described in this thread do not exist.

I do not find a file settings.gradle somewhere.

When I add

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

to my build.grade file, I get an error message about this new line.

To sum it up: none of the things described there works with the new version. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have `<action ... MAIN>` declared on any activity from **Manifest.xml** file?

Comment: Yes, it is there: <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally only one method worked: create a new, empty project in Android Studio without any pregenerated code/activities and copy the old sources into the related folders. Only in this case this fu***** Grade-crap was configured properly and building of the "old" project worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue.

I removed my project from Android studio.
And then opened it again but this time I clicked on "Import Project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.)" and not "Open an existing Android Studio Project"

[image]

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Close your project. Import the module in your project by clicking File->New Import project . You are just selecting the wrong folder while importing.

Comment: I'm using the folder where the Manifest-file is contained in. What would be the correct folder instead?

Comment: try selecting the module folder. Not sure.